# Is the rank of the elliptic curve x^3 + y^3 = a(n), where a(n) is the n-th cubefree taxicab number, known?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Is the rank of the elliptic curve x^3 + y^3 = a(n) over the rationals, where a(n) is the n-th cubefree taxicab number A080642(n) in the OEIS, known?

Comment: For partial results towards this see Silverman's paper http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/images/upload_library/22/Ford/silverman331-340.pdf .  In particular it says that the rank of the elliptic curve is bounded below in terms of the number of solutions to the taxicab equation (see page 339).  I am not aware of a more precise solution.

Comment: In Unsolved Problems in Number Theory, 3rd edition, section D1, 2004, R. K. Guy says, "Andrew Bremner has computed the rational rank of the elliptic curve x^3 + y^3 = Taxicab(n) as equal to 2, 4, 5, 4 for n = 2, 3, 4, 5, respectively." But Taxicab(n) equals A011541(n), not the cubefree taxicab number A080642(n). @Lucia

Comment: I think the answer to this question is simply: **no.**